# Set custom font for the entire app (including navigation bars, labels, textfields, buttons, everything)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set a font for the entire app that includes navigation bars, labels, textfields, buttons and everything else.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
UILabel.appearance().font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .init(rawValue: "Roboto"))
```

Is there any simple way to do this rather than manually setting a custom font for eveything?

Comment: In short: no, there's not.